How to remove a header in restassured / cucumber / java
I am using restassured with cucumber and java
I set some headers in the Background:
Background: Set Headers
    And headers
      | Content-Type      | application/json |
      | Accept            | application/json |
      | Source-Identifier | test             |


I have one scenario where I want to test NOT sending the Source-Identifier header.
Is there any way or removing a header in restassured?
I don't really want to create a new Feature File just for that one test.

You would add at step to your scenario that says And the "Source-Identifier" header is not included. Then in that step remove the header from the request.

I know that - but how do you remove a header in restassured? There is an addheader method but no removeheader method as far as I can see.

I think you can only do that in a .filter().
